# Gettin EOFError on VIM with Python3 code

Tags: python, macos, eoferror

I'm a beginner and am having the following problem: whenever I execute the following script (I'm using Python 3.6) on VIM:

```
def main():
    print("This program illustrates a chaotic function")
    x=eval(input("Enter a number between 0 and 1: "))
    for i in range(10):
        x=3.9*x*(1-x)
        print(x)
main()
```

I always get an `EOFError` only when I recall the `main()`at the end. What I get is:

```
This program illustrates a chaotic function
Enter a number between 0 and 1: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in main
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

and don't understand why, especially because I had tried it some weeks ago and it worked perfectly, flinging me over to the shell to input the value. Don't know what happened in between or what the problem may be.

Comment: Why are you using `eval` for `float`s? And could you give a [mcve] with a traceback?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you are executing your script with Python 2, where [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#input) already uses `eval()`. Instead, either execute your script with Python 3, or use the Python 2 [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#raw_input) function.

Also, you don't need to use `eval` to convert a user-inputted string of a float to an actual float; just use `float()`:

```
x = float(raw_input("Enter a number between 0 and 1: "))
```

Replace `raw_input()` with `input()` if you are using Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
# For Python2
# Replace the line:
x=eval(input("Enter a number between 0 and 1: "))
# with:
x=input("Enter a number between 0 and 1: ")

# For Python3, the line:
x=eval(input("Enter a number between 0 and 1: "))
# should work
```

Use the command ***python*** followed by the filename for Python2 and use the command ***python3*** followed by the filename for Python3

**Python3:**

```
python3 example.py
```

**Python2:**

```
python example.py
```

Learn more from [here](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_input.php).

Comment: I have Python3 and that's exactly the line I have.

Comment: Use another editor like "nano". Your code works when I edited with Sublime Text 2. It may just be some unnecessary characters that is causing the problem.